# SSIS Visual Studio 2015 Woes With 'Testing Connectivity'

Tags: ssis, freeze, connectivity

Visual Studio 2015 (SSDT 2016) is driving me mad the last couple of weeks with freezing and showing 'Testing Connectivity' in the status bar.

My project has 4 project scope connection managers all OLEDB, everything bog standard. When I open VS without a package file opening on start-up all is good. Then I can go into each of the 4 connection managers and press 'Test Connectivity' and they all return successfully in under a second.

However, when I now open a package it still reverts to 'Testing Connectivity' and hangs there forever.

Also when I verify those 4 databases in SSMS they are all active with no problem.

It only started about a couple of weeks ago and it is actually preventing me from working now. Since this behaviour is recent I must assume something changed within our infrastructure, but I cant find what that would be especially, since all the connection managers individually test successfully.

Any ideas?

Regards

Carsten

Comment: Can you check the project parameters for the connection managers?  Could be something funny there.  Also, if you are using passwords in the parameters and these are marked as sensitive, that might be going null when you open the package.  In those cases, you might mark them as not sensitive while you do your development and set them back before you check in your code.

Comment: Are there any tasks with complicated sql in them? It may be that VS is validating the tasks and it might take some toime for it to do that. I know it says "testing connectivity" but the ui doesn't always keep up. If you don't need any connectivity, you can set to work offline from the SSIS-menu.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. None of the two things apply. No password parameters only whats defined in the connections managers themselves and no complicated SQL either. Like I said I can validate the connection managers individually without a problem.
Strange thing is that it doesnt happen if I connect via ethernet (vs wireless). Which I dont understand because in either case there goes VPN on top of it. But either way it points to a infrastructure configuration issue rather than a VS or SQL issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the .vs hidden folder in the solution directory fixed this.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't fix it for me